# How to view login user data in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I joined two table.
One classrooms and another joinclass table. 
Here is my classrooms table
[image]

And here is my joinclass table
[image]

Here is my `controller`:

```
public function std_classes(Request $request)
    {

        $data = DB::table('classrooms')
        ->join('joinclass', 'classrooms.class_code', '=', 'joinclass.class_code')->get();


        return View::make('std_classes')->with('data',$data);
    }
```

And here is my view

```
@if(Auth::check())
@foreach($data as $data)
<h1>{{$data->class_name}}</h1>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Now in my view here show classrooms data.
But i want to view only login user data that's why i used `@if(Auth::check())`
But still now its view all data. 
Why  `@if(Auth::check())` condition not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need a clarifications, do you want to show only the data of the user that is actually logged in? In that case you should not use `@if(Auth::check())` because it returns true if a user is logged and then cicle all the foreach data. 
In that case you shoud check the logged user after the foreach, something like that:

```
@foreach($data as $data)
   @if(Auth::user()->id == $data->user_id)
       <h1>{{$data->class_name}}</h1>
   @endif
@endforeach
```